# Writing a "recommendation letter" for a supervisor from a student?

Tags: etiquette, recommendation-letter, university

As a thank you to my thesis supervisor, I would like to write some sort of letter expressing my gratitude for the work he has done for me.

I was wondering if students ever write letters in such a way that they can be used by professors as a sort of "reference" letter when applying for jobs or teaching grants. For reference, my supervisor is a Senior Lecturer at a university in the Australian system. Would a letter like this be appreciated? What should it look like?

Comment: Such an acknowledge will presumably appear in the acknowledgement section of your dissertation/thesis. That said, I see nothing wrong with extending whatever you write in the acknowledgements section to something longer. I think it is more appropriate for such a letter to be kept private, hence, there's no need to write it in "such a way that they can be used by professors as a sort of 'reference' letter when applying for jobs or teaching grants." (I don't know what a "teaching grant" is. Did you mean research grant?)

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about the Australian system; in the US, it's quite normal for applications for promotion and teaching awards to require letters from students (though I think usually students from classes, rather than doctoral students).  However, I wouldn't pre-emptively write one; my recommendation is that you write a letter or email, in which you could offer if they ever need such a letter.  The other thing you could reasonably do is write a short email to their head of department, just saying in a few sentences wy you felt that they were successful as a supervisor.  That's probably the best way to help their career.

Comment: _it's quite normal for applications for promotion...to require letters from students_ — Letters from former students are **expressly forbidden** in promotion cases at my university.

Comment: Fair enough.  They were required at UVA; I said "normal," not universal.

Answer (score 0):

In North America the website LinkedIn is very popular. My present supervisor has several recommendations from past graduate students on his profile. This essentially consists of a short paragraph relaying the supervisor's strengths and professional abilities. It is publicly available, so this will help to make his profile/work stand out for potential future students and collaborators. I would recommend something along these lines.